# jquery binding same event to 2 selectors

Tags: jquery

I have two classes: Class1 and Class2.

For now, I have 2 function calls calling the same MyFunction function:

```
$('.Class1').click(function () { MyFunction() });
$('.Class2').click(function () { MyFunction() });
```

How do I rewrite this to say "when there's a click on Class1 and on Class2 call MyFunction".

Thanks.

Comment: AND or OR ?  Clearly you cannot click to objects at the same time.

Comment: Do you mean "or" when you say  "when there's a click on Class1 and on Class2 call MyFunction".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
$('.Class1, .Class2').click(function () { MyFunction() })
```

Answer (score 3):

to bind a click event to 2 different classes

`$('.Class1, .Class2').click()`

this would mean if `Class1 OR Class2` is clicked, fire the event.